# Does Wall of Blades (Warblade maneuver) work against touch attacks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

The maneuver Wall of Blades reads:

> When an enemy makes a melee attack or ranged attack against you, you
>   can initiate this counter to oppose that attack by making an attack
>   roll with any melee weapon you are holding. Use the higher of your AC
>   or your attack roll as your effective AC against the incoming attack 
>   *Tome of Battle, p. 70*

Do the attacks mentioned here include touch attacks and ranged touch attacks or would they have to be specifically mentioned?

In case ranged touch attacks are legal targets of this counter I suspect that you could deflect rays with this maneuver, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, it does.

These are the [touch attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/combatStatistics.htm#touchAttacks) rules:

> Some attacks disregard armor, including shields and natural armor. In these cases, the attacker makes a touch attack roll (either ranged or melee).

A touch attack is still a kind of attack, since there is an attack roll. So it doesn't get around *wall of blades* the same way that, say, a *fog cloud* spell would (since the latter doesn't have an attack roll, so it's not an attack).

> When you are the target of a touch attack, your AC doesn’t include any armor bonus, shield bonus, or natural armor bonus.

A touch attack is defined by what it ignores, rather than by what it allows. *Wall of blades* does not provide an armor bonus, shield bonus, or natural armor bonus. Indeed, it's not a bonus at all. Therefore, the full AC you get from *wall of blades* applies against touch attacks.

Yes, this means you can block lasers with your sword.

Comment: And grapple attempts, touch spells and several other nuisances. I like that.